# incremental crawl question

Tags: 2007, windows-server

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 on Windows Server 2008. I am using Search Center to crawl web data source (i.e. crawl web page from other web sites). My question is about incremental crawl, I want to know for incremental crawl, if the Url of a web server data source itself does not change, but the Url's content is updated (e.g. daily update news page on a web site's specific front page Url), if I set crawl to be incremental crawling, will it be re-crawled and store the lastest content of the Url?

Appreciate if anyone could provide any document to prove the exact behavior.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice summary of incremental vs. full crawl behavior here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointsearch/thread/af86399b-c1e7-4f1b-a54e-2aaafa55b173

I cannot find documentation to support those statements, but it matches our server's typical behavior.  If you augment that information with the article at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280343%28office.12%29.aspx, then I expect that it will behave like you want it to: indexing the new information that exists on the web URLs that you set it to crawl.